# onCreate wasn't called by the main class

Tags: android, oncreate

I've read a lot of articles but none of them could fix my problem of not calling the onCreate-method in the class XMLParsingExample.

The log-statement in the onCreate didn't show output and tracing shows that the class is exited after boolean finished=false and thus not running the onCreate.

Here the codes:

```
public class MyMap extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;
private MapController mc;
private OverlayItem overlayItem;
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
private Drawable drawable;
private Drawable drawable2;
private MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlayMyLoc;
private MyItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlayRust;
private LocationManager locMgr;
private MyLocationListener locLstnr;XMLParsingExample mXMLParsingExample;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        locMgr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locLstnr = new MyLocationListener();
        locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locLstnr);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // first overlay
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2);
        itemizedOverlayMyLoc = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);

        //                                  LAT                 LONG
        GeoPoint uwLoc = new GeoPoint((int)(52.22778*1E6),(int)(6.10428*1E6));
        overlayItem = new OverlayItem(uwLoc, "Uw locatie", "http://www.nu.nl");
        itemizedOverlayMyLoc.addOverlay(overlayItem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlayMyLoc);

        // Rustpunten overlay
        drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rmarker3);
        itemizedOverlayRust = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable2, mapView);

        mXMLParsingExample = new XMLParsingExample();
```

and here the class which where the oncreate isn't called:

```
public class XMLParsingExample extends Activity {

/** Create Object For SiteList Class */
public SitesList sitesList = null;
public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
boolean finished=false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("onCreate", "onCreate started");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binyamin Sharet is correct.

I think you are confusing a creator method, which does get called when you allocate an object, and `onCreate()`, which is an Android lifecycle callback function that gets called automatically by the framework at the appropriate time.

A creator function doesn't usually have 'create' in its name; it shares the name of the class whose object you are instantiating.  In your case, the creator would be called `XMLParsingExample()`.

For more information about Android lifecycle callbacks, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html.

Comment: Oke thanks for these answers I will check them later out but it looks promising

Answer (score 4):

Starting a new Activity is not done by instantiating it (`new XMLParsingExample();`), but with an intent, for example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, XMLParsingExample.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Take a look at the [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).